# How to shade shapes in tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I managed to draw the rectangle and a triangle inside with the below code.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0) rectangle (4,-3);
\draw(0,0) -- ++(4,-1.5) -- ++(-2,-1.5) -- ++(-2,3);
\draw[dotted](0,0) to[bend left] node[fill=white] {$2b$} (4,0);
\draw[dotted](0,0) to[bend right] node[fill=white] {$a$} (0,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Now I want to shade the triangle.
How would you go about doing this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple add `fill=gray` (or what ever color) into drawing a triangle, something like:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw   (0,0) rectangle (4,-3);
\draw[fill=gray!30]    (0,0) -- ++(4,-1.5) -- ++(-2,-1.5) -- ++(-2,3);
\draw[dotted](0,0) to[bend left] node[fill=white] {$2b$} (4,0);
\draw[dotted](0,0) to[bend right] node[fill=white] {$a$} (0,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Replace `\draw` with `\shadedraw`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0) rectangle (4,-3);
\shadedraw (0,0) -- ++(4,-1.5) -- ++(-2,-1.5) -- ++(-2,3);
\draw[dotted](0,0) to[bend left] node[fill=white] {$2b$} (4,0);
\draw[dotted](0,0) to[bend right] node[fill=white] {$a$} (0,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Zarko's answer is perhaps more what you're after, I took the `shade` part a bit literally in the TikZ sense.

Comment: However, I like your solution ... it shows a power  of TikZ/pgf package as well that for nice drawings you should be aware of huge number of its possibilities :-) , so I vote for  your answer.

Comment: The gradient shading looks beautiful though. I'll be using it at some point for sure. Thank you so much!